# Watin - Cannot find link element (Javascript)

Tags: watin

I'm using watin to automate a process on a web system (internal).

I can open the website and access some links, but others cannot be found. I think this may be either because they are deeply nested or because the href is javascript. This is the format they are in:

```
    <frame>
     <html>
      <frameset>
       <frame>
        <html>
         <body>
          <div>
           <table>
            <table>
             <tr>
              <td>
               <a id="1_1_1_a" href="javascript:blah" </a>
```

I've tried various different ways to find by id, element type etc. But I'm stuck on this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elements within a frame have to be searched through its frame because each frame is considered a separate namespace in WatIn. So first get the correct frame (by calling the Frame method or through the Frames property - note that in your example you must do it twice as you have two nested frames) and then search for the link, e.g.:

```
ie.Frames[0].Frames[0].Link("1_1_1_a")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I've tried to use Frame(Find.ByName) and Frame(Frind.BySrc) to identify the frame, but it's not able to find the frame either.

Is there a way I can view what elements watin can access/see?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        using (var browser = new IE("your_web_site_here"))
        {
            try
            {
            Frame first_frame = browser.Frame(Find.ById("frame_1_id"));
            Frame second_frame = first_frame.Frame(Find.ById("frame_2_id"));
            var first_div = second_frame.Div(Find.ById("first_div_id"));
            Assert.IsTrue(first_div.Exists);
            var Link_to_click = first_div.Link(Find.ById("1_1_1_a"));
            Assert.IsTrue(Link_to_click.Exists);
            Link_to_click.Click();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
         }
```

Sometimes watin cannot find elements I'm still trying to find out why and what are the preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my test would browse to a page that had 40 links on it and even though you could see all the links on the page the following statement would show links (and other elements collections) had a count of zero.

```
ie.Links.Count();
```

I'm still not sure exactly what the underlying issue is but I discovered that if you start Gallio Icarus / Gallio Echo / Visual Studio (or whatever test runner you are using) by **Right Click -> Run as administrator** the test works as expected and the elements are loaded into the ie browser object correctly.